# Корректное подключение сторонней библиотеки к Qt-Android проекту

Tags: android, qt, библиотеки

Здравствуйте!

Работаю с [**mapbox-gl**](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native) для отрисовки карт.

Т.к. JAVA никогда не использовал, приходится все делать на C++.

Собрал динамическую библиотеку **libmapbox-gl.so** на ОС Ubuntu, как указано в документации к Mapbox (командой make-android) под архитектуру **armeabi-v7a**.

После чего создал пустой проект в Qt. В .pro файле подключаю собранную библиотеку:

```
contains(ANDROID_TARGET_ARCH,armeabi-v7a)
 { 
   ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS = \
   $$PWD/../Desktop/mapbox-gl-native/build/android-arm-v7/Release/lib.target/libmapbox-gl.so
 }
```

При отсутствии данной библиотеки пустой проект с кнопочной на форме запускается на устройстве без проблем. При подключении данной библиотеки, приложение вылетает сразу после запуска с критической ошибкой.

В дебаге выводится ошибка о том, что  JNI не может загрузить данную библиотеку.

В чем может быть проблема? Корректно ли описанным выше способом подключать библиотеку, собранную под  android? Либо есть способ установить библиотеку предварительно на устройство?

После сборки библиотеки создается также тестовый проект под Android Studio. Последний запускается корректно.
Использую версию Qt 5.4

Answer (score 1):

В общем последовательность такая:

1. Кладём файлы библиотек в директорию "android/libs" нашего проекта.
2. Прописываем путь к ним в .pro файле LIBS += -L"path of the lib" -llibname
3. В файле "android/res/values/libs.xml" дописать следующие строки:

> ```
> <array name="ЛЮБОЕ_ИМЯ">
> <item>ИМЯ_БИБЛИОТЕКИ_1(без расширения)</item>
> <item>ИМЯ_БИБЛИОТЕКИ_2</item>
> ...
> </array>
> ```

4. В файле "androidManifest.xml" найти строку:  и заменить "bundled_libs" на "ЛЮБОЕ_ИМЯ" - то, что написали в "libs.xml"
5. Теперь при сборке .APK файла, библиотека будет в него включена.

Я так подключал библиотеку SFML, правда при сборке компилятор попросил ещё несколько библиотек, добавил их так же.